# MySQL - How To Query Results With Match Of Middle Text/Digits

Tags: mysql, center

Imagine a column in table with digits and text, from 1001 to fa00ty and even 01100001 or longer, there's millions of rows of data. I want to query the table and return rows with only "00" or maybe just "0" in the "exact middle of the text/digits of the column". Example table

```
|some00e  |
|01100001 |
|fa00ty   |
|m00ol    |
|23_00_asd|
|some long string with 00 some long string with|
```

---

There are only two matching results for "00" which would be fa00ty as 00 is exactly center of this text and 'some long string with 00 some long string with' and two for the single 0 query. So odd or even length does not matter.

Comment: You can exclude strings with **odd** length upfront.

Comment: @PM77-1 , even odd digits/strings could have center digit needed. I've updated question to account for this

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go with something like this:

```
SELECT stuff 
FROM test 
WHERE  
  (substring(stuff FROM (0-length(stuff)/2)-1 for 2) = "00"
  AND (length(stuff) % 2 = 0))
OR
  (substring(stuff FROM (0-ROUND(length(stuff)/2)) for 1) = "0" 
  AND (length(stuff) % 2 != 0))
```

This will only return even numbers (i.e. so the exact middle can be two digits) whose middle digits are '00', or odd numbers whose middle digit is '0'.

Comment: That's not in the question or comments - rather, the opposite, and X00Y should be returned as '00' is in the middle of the string.  I'd suggest you read it again.

Comment: Very interesting query - thank you for the feedback with that. Surely works, and It takes about 1 1/2 second on 571k rows.

Comment: To clarify, my first comment was directed at a comment by another used that has now been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Following query works much faster. Still unsure if it is the best answer as I am not query knowledgeable, thus awaiting other possible solutions. Also will not work with anything greater than 3 digits as far as I could test.

For 2 digits

```
MID(`stuff`,round(LENGTH(`stuff`)/2),2) = '00' AND LENGTH(`stuff`)%2=0
```

For 1 digit

```
MID(`stuff`,round(LENGTH(`stuff`)/2),1) = '0' AND LENGTH(`stuff`)%2
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, `MID` is purely a synonym for `substring(string, pos, len)`, so it would be interesting to know how much quicker it is.
The only real difference between the two is that I counted backwards rather than forwards, so it's curious to know how much of an impact that makes :)